# Compare DateTime null value in SQL and in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I am trying to use compare dates in a query. I have d and p are rows selected from different datatables.I want to retrieve fields from datatables based on condition. I have below conditions but throwing an error when any one of the below date is Null or empty.

I tried below statements-

```
join d in Data.AsEnumerable()
                    on p.Field<String>("EMPLID") equals
                    d.Field<String>("EMPLID")
 where (Convert.ToString(d.Field<DateTime>("CONTRACT_START"))!=null) &&  (Convert.ToString(d.Field<DateTime>("SIGNED_DT"))!=null) && (Convert.ToString(d.Field<String>("ACT_DT"))!=null)
```

Throwing an error- Can not cast DBNull.Value to Sysytem .date Time . Please use a nullable types.

when above condition is true( values are not null then I want to exceute below statement in a query)

```
 where (d.Field<DateTime>("CONTRACT_START") >= sd && d.Field<DateTime>("CONTRACT_START") <= ed) ||Convert.ToString(d.Field<DateTime>("SIGNED_DT"))!=" " && d.Field<DateTime>("SIGNED_DT") > d.Field<DateTime>("CONTRACT_START") || d.Field<DateTime>("ACT_DT") > d.Field<DateTime>("CONTRACT_START"))
```

How to check if the values are not null then execute the condition using in a query in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's cause your value is `null` in your datatable. You should change the line in your `where` condition to be (notice the nullable DateTime `DateTime?`)

```
(Convert.ToString(d.Field<DateTime?>("CONTRACT_START"))!=null)
```

Comment: I tried this but still getting an errorjoin d in Data.AsEnumerable()
                    on p.Field<String>("EMPLID") equals
                    d.Field<String>("EMPLID")

Comment: (Convert.ToString(d.Field<DateTime?>("CONTRACT_START"))!=null && (Convert.ToString(d.Field<DateTime?>("SIGNED_DT"))!=null) && (Convert.ToString(d.Field<DateTime?>("GRANTACT_DT"))!=null))
                where (d.Field<DateTime?>("CONTRACT_START") >= sd && d.Field<DateTime?>("CONTRACT_START") <= ed) || (d.Field<DateTime?>("SIGNED_DT") > hcmd.Field<DateTime?>("CONTRACT_START")

Comment: Can not cast DBNull.Value to System.DateTime

Comment: Is there any way we can add 1/1/1900 date value if it is null and then check if that date is > sd in query itself.

Comment: It worked i am not getting any errors . But just want to understand whow exactly < DateTime? > is checking null value in  (Convert.ToString(d.Field<DateTime?>("CONTRACT_START"))!=null)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not proficient in MySql, but you are definately using [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) the wrong way. In c# [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) is struct, which means it cannot be `null`.

You have to use [Nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) dates in your c# project instead ([MSDN: Using Nullable Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types)):

```
DateTime? dateTime;
```